# Backticks in tags

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, tag-wiki

I was going through the review queue and came across a change to a tag wiki excerpt that consisted of removing the backticks around certain words that were appropriate for code blocks. After looking at the tag wiki excerpt in question I noticed that to me, even though they weren't code blocks, the use of backticks was making the words stand out in the way that a code block would.

Question: Do people find backticks in tag wiki excerpts sometimes useful even though they don't render as code, or is it just me and I should let the edit go through?

**EDIT**

Just to give an example of what I was actually looking at, this is the excerpt that was edited to remove the back ticks:

Python module providing a high-level interface for fetching data across the World Wide Web, predecessor to urllib2. In Python 3, `urllib2` and `urllib` have been reorganized and merged into `urllib`.

The reason that I like the backticks despite their lack of functionality is that "urllib" and "urllib2" are proper nouns that are the main subject of the excerpt. I think that the reason that I like to see emphasis is that I'm used to seeing these terms in a monospace typeset and seeing them in a proportional font with no emphasis just looks weird.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm sorry, I'm not terribly familiar with the terms. I'm talking about what shows up when you mouse over a tag (or at least the description part thereof). Is that an excerpt?

Comment: Yes, that's an excerpt. Making this comment useful---my question would be, why would you need to put code in an excerpt? It's supposed to be a very short description of the tag.

Comment: Well, yay for that edit, back-ticks are grossly abused.  How often do you see a book or a news-paper or magazine article or a web page that does this?  *Italic* and **bold** are appropriate typography mechanisms to emphasize words.  But there are some SO users that think it is appropriate, I suspect their college books had a lot of yellow highlight marks.  Very hard to discuss taste.

Comment: I am agnostic on whether they should be shown as code blocks, but right now it's confusing as markdown formatting works almost *everywhere* on the site *except* in tag excerpts. To make matters worse, there is no preview for tag excerpts so you have no way of knowing that it doesn't work. And to make it *even more* confusing, [the history does interpret the tags](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8355818/revisions). Either interpret them or strip them (same applies to other inline formatting such as \*, \*\*, \_, and \_\_ and in a lesser degree to tag links such as  [tag:urllib2]).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The markdown implementation on this site is weird. Comments use a slightly different set of rules from questions and answers, and anything that looks like XML or HTML is auto-stripped, rather than auto-escaped. It would be nice if someone took on the task of reviewing it and making it consistent and useful, as I suspect a lot of the underlying code just hasn't been touched in years.

Comment: So, um, why isn't markdown supported in tag excerpts?

Comment: It's a tag wiki excerpt the back ticks markdown syntax doesn't work there so it's pointless having them.

Answer (score 6):

In a normal post, backticking `urllib2` is appropriate. A Python module name, like a function or class name, is something that you type directly in your code. It's thus appropriate to backtick it. If there were a distinct human name, like *URL Library 2*, that was different from the module name `urllib2` used in code, then *that* wouldn't be appropriate to backtick, but backticking `urllib2` is correct.

The [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) for `urllib2` consistently use `<code>` tags for `urllib2`, so they evidently believe that the name is code. I don't see any reason to disagree with them.

However, in a tag wiki excerpt where the backticks don't get parsed and will just be rendered literally, they're ugly. Leave them out, and edit them out if you see them.

Answer (score 5):

Markdown syntax is specifically for marking code, so people using backticks for non-code are simply making a mistake. You should reject edits that add them and/or replace the backticks with emphasis marks meant for prose, like *italic* or **bold**. Edits removing them *from prose* should be approved, assuming there is no necessary emphasis lost in the process. If there is, just add appropriate emphasis as mentioned above.

However, all markdown in wiki excerpts is ignored, so any kind of emphasis there would be inappropriate.

Don't forget to explain your rejection or edit, especially if you see multiple edits by one person making this mistake.

Comment: The OP was asking about an edit that _removed_ the vestigial back-ticks, while your answer appears to address the opposite; the _addition_ of markdown symbols. Further, all markdown in a wiki excerpt is ignored, so adding prose marks does nothing to improve readability either.

Comment: @Mogsdad Thanks; edited to cover both scenarios.

Comment: @TylerH Just added an example of what I'm talking about. Let me know if you have any ideas (basically I prefer `urllib` and `urllib2` to have some sort of emphasis). Might just be a preference thing where everyone else likes it the way it is too.

Comment: You _could_ simply italicise _urllib_ and _urllib2_

Comment: @CrazyCasta I'd go with what Tas said; italicize them when talking about them. Only encode them when they are called or named *in a code snippet* (not necessarily a Stack Snippet, but any snippet of code)... and code snippets usually don't belong in tag excerpts. Usually you don't need them in tag description pages, either.

Comment: I apply the "for marking code" part to include calls to binaries but not names of libraries. For example, since bash is technically an code interpreter, `ls` would be ok, but `libc6.so` would not, since calling it in the interpreter would fail (and make no sense).

Comment: @Tas How would I do that in a tag excerpt? It's my understanding from the conversation here that tag excerpts don't support any kind of formatting.

Comment: @CrazyCasta You can't do it in a tag excerpt. You can only use plain text in a tag excerpt.

Answer (score 3):

[Markdown is meant to be human readable even when not rendered.](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) Additionally, `urllib2` is a technical identifier for the package. When you use `pip` or something, you type `pip install urllib2`.

Therefore, keeping the back ticks is a good idea.

Comment: Markdown may be meant to be human readable even when not rendered, but that doesn't mean it is more readable than without syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure what your `pip` example demonstrates. Should we backtick `install`, even when it's not being used as an argument to `pip`?

Comment: @IMSoP sure, if it's being used as a formal identifier. `urllib2` is the machine readable name of the URL Library version 2.